# How to automatically start chromedrivre with nightwatch?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

**config**

```
{
    "src_folders": [
        "test/e2e"
    ],
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": false,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver"
        }
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "selenium_port": 9515,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "default_path_prefix": "",
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        "--no-sandbox"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test

```
module.exports = {
    'index page': function (client) {
        client
            .url('http://localhost:8080')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .assert.title('Apidae')
            .end();
    }
};
```

#### Run

To make it work I run two command in different tabs:
1. start `chromedriver`

```
./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver
```

2. start my test:

```
./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch
```

#### Question

How can I modify my `nightwatch` config to start the `chromedriver` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Hikaryu answer, please **upvote his answer**,here is my full configuration:

#### Package.json

I check for selenium before launching the test (could be a separate script).

```
"scripts": {
  "test:e2e": "node ./test/selenium-download.js; ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "nightwatch": "0.9.x",
  "selenium-download": "^2.0.10",
}
```

#### Checking selenium presence script

Based on [selenium-download](https://github.com/groupon/selenium-download) example:

```
var selenium = require('selenium-download');

selenium.ensure(__dirname + '/bin', function (error) {
  if (error) console.error(error.stack);
  process.exit(0);
});
```

#### nightwatch.json

I updated some keys/values, removed `default_path_prefix` field.

```
{
    "src_folders": [
        "test/e2e"
    ],
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "./test/bin/selenium.jar",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "test/bin/chromedriver"
        }
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": { "args": [ "--no-sandbox" ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test directory

```
./test/
├── bin
│   ├── chromedriver
│   └── selenium.jar
├── *.tests.js
└── e2e
    └── index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'selenium': { // downloaded by selenium-download module (see readme)
    'start_process': true, // tells nightwatch to start/stop the selenium process
    'server_path': './node_modules/selenium/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': 4444, // standard selenium port
    'cli_args': { // chromedriver is downloaded by selenium-download (see readme)
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': './node_modules/nightwatch/bin/chromedriver'
    }
```

And add this to test_settings

```
  'chrome': {
      'desiredCapabilities': {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'javascriptEnabled': true // turn off to test progressive enhancement
      }
```

It is working for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will post my complete configuration for clarity